# How to modify Database from UI in Meteor App

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor and want to modify database document from the user interface,

I understand that we have to use [update function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update) but unable to use it as I want to edit the collection from UI on click command, please suggest how to go about it.

Arguments

**selector** Mongo Selector, Object ID, or String

```
Specifies which documents to modify
```

**modifier** Mongo Modifier

```
Specifies how to modify the documents
```

**callback** Function

```
**Optional**. If present, called with an error object as the first argument and, if no error, the number of affected documents as the second.
```

Please suggest how to use modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets put this on an example, using an event handler.

```
Template.example.events({
 'click #updateThis':function(e,t){
   var newValue = t.$('.newValue').val(); // taking value from random input
   Collection.update({_id:this._id},{$set:{value:newValue}},function(error,result){
      if(error){
        console.log(error.reason)
       }else{
        console.log("Nice update")
       }
    })
  }
})
```

So first the **Selector**, like it says it should be the `ID` of the document to modify.

the modifier in this example is the [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) more [about field update operators here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/)

and the **callback** is to make it asynchronous, with the 2 parameters i like to use `error` and `result`

Comment: say my table has two variables: book name and price, how can I do it?

Comment: just change to this `{book:bookName,price:bookPrice}`

Comment: Hey Ethaan , its not working :( . I have to make the fields editable?

Comment: @garima give me 10min i will make a minimal example on meteorpad

Comment: Here is the [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/98hJsa8prijium2h4/Leaderboard) @garima

Comment: @garima the data im editing on the meteor pad its from the db, or maybe i don't get the comment

Comment: for eg the table has multiple rows: bookname,price as (A,25),(B,30),(C,40),(E,50) I want to edit one variable say E to D..there I am stuck up

Comment: well it will be great if you create a new question about this, since this SO was already answered, or edit the question with more detail information